# Positioning a div inside of an overlay

Tags: html, css, overlay, css-position

Trying to create a contact form in an overlay.  I have the overlay div working, but it only works if I set it to "position: absolute".  The div inside of the overlay, will not position properly, regardless of what I try.

Need the "form-wrap to be centered vertically & horizontally.

```
<div id="overlay">
    <div id="form-wrap">
        <img id="close-btn" src="images/framework/close.png">
        <form id="form-box">
            <input name="first-name" id="first-name" type="text" maxlength="32">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

#overlay{
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 899;
    display: none;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.41);
}
#form-wrap{
    width: 400px;
    height: 600px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 900;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
#overlay{
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 899;
    display: none;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.41);
}
#form-wrap{
    width: 400px;
    height: 600px;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -300px 0 0 -200px;
    background-color: white;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/9MkCF/)

Comment: I am definitely going to try this, but as a quick question, could I just use {top: 0; bottom:0; right:0; left:0;}? If not any resource would be much appreciated.  Thanks much.

Comment: if you use that then it will fill 100% of the container, giving four co-ordinates instead of two will mean it is positioned and sized relative to it's parent whereas if you only give an x and a y then you will need to give it a width and a height

Comment: This all worked up until today, when I realized that if the window isn't maximized, the form-wrap will be higher up or further to the left.

Comment: @JohnFasano did you change the dimensions of the form wrap? you need to margin it top minus half the height and then margin left minus half the width

Comment: Sorry, just seen that I used position relative for the form-wrap, it should be 1position:absolute`: http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/9MkCF/1/

Comment: That definitely worked, just wondering, what if it had a dynamic height and width.  Is that even possible?  Thanks!

Comment: if it had a dynamic height and width you'd have to use a bit of js to position it centrally

Answer (score 0):

This will only work if the height of your overlay is greater than 600px!

```
#overlay{
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 899;
    display: none;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.41);
}
#form-wrap{
    width: 400px;
    height: 600px;
    top: 50%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 900;
    margin: -300px auto 0 auto;
    background-color: white;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/vHs7R/1/)